# Computing divisibility and multiplication

Tags: java, console, calculator

Please check my Java program to see if I use the global variables, nested loops and two functions with parameters correctly. I would also like any suggestions to improve my program.

```
import java.util.*;
public class javaProgram {

    public static int loopCount = 0;
    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void div(int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                System.out.print("The number " + i + " is divisible by:");
                for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                    if ((i % j) == 0)
                        System.out.print(" " + j);                
                    loopCount++;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
       }

     private static void mul(int n) {   
                System.out.println();       
                System.out.println("Multiplication table for "+n);      
                System.out.println("---------------------------");  
                for(int i = 1; i<=10;i++) {  
                    System.out.format("%2d x %d = %3d\n", i,n,i*n); 
                    loopCount++;
                }
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Let's compute for divisible and multiplication!");
            System.out.print("Enter number of integers: ");     
            int number = scanner.nextInt();  
            div(number);
            mul(number);
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Loop count " + loopCount);
        }

}
```

Comment: What would be the role of `loopCount` ?

Comment: The largest value that a number can be divisible by(excluding itself) is the number divided by the smallest prime divisor(smallest prime divisor is not 1). For instance the number 15 the smallest prime divisor is 3 so 15/3 = 5 so 5 will be as far as you need to search in your FOR LOOP. That should save you a lot of unnecessary iterations. If you can't find a prime divisor that is less than or equal to the square root of the number then it is only divisible by 1 and itself

Comment: You also have some scoping issues. I see privates and publics and a package scope(because no scope specified), but everything can be private except for main, if it is in the same class

Answer (score 1):

#### Review

> *see if I use the global variables, nested loops and two functions with parameters correctly*

- `loopCount` is a magic variable, its meaning beats me. Is it some kind of debugging assistant?
- The indentations seem random picks between 4 and 8 spaces. Stick to 4.
- The `div` method is public, the `mul` private. Why introduce this inconsistency?
- Give full names to your methods for readabiliy `divide`, `multiply`.
- The methods are void, printing the results to the console. This limits usability to zero. Separate interaction with the console from the method flow. Use *return* values to yield results. Let `main` log these results to the console.
- As suggested in the comments, you can optimize division by probing the smallest prime divisor to minimize cycles in the loops.
- Be a bit more consistent in aligning brackets with method declarations.
- For readability and consistency, add a blank line after the imports and remove that blank line after the last method.